# Magento Multi store products from different root category in same page on website level

Tags: magento, store

I struggled a lot to find a solution for that with Magento CE, but I still don't know how to do it.
What I would like to have is a website with multi store on different domains, and this seems to be  easy if checking on docs.
Then I need on default domain/store to share all products from different root category/stores all together and let the user buy from different stores without have to switch between stores.

I don't know how to achieve this and I can't find any point to figure it out.

It is possible to do it simply with a config of basic Magento or should I have to do it programmatically?

Comment: Tnks Mayerz for the edit.

Comment: This is a multistore instance on different domains  Flip between Tiemart and bowtiemart in the header.    go to www.tiemart.com    is this what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Yes it seems to be what I need. I don't know how to have bowtie store's products on tiemart home. If I create two store and two root category I have separated products. In yoru site (nice website) you have for ex. the "Red Silk Band Collar Bow Tie" with COD. AC00BB-0001 in tiemart and also in bowtiemart. That's what I need a big website with all products together on main domain and just products from a specific store in a secondary domain. but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Hey Rob, can you please point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that I did not respond right away. You can have two stores and two root categories. You just have to make sure the product is assigned to both.  This is how the store you checked out is setup.   As you can see both stores are part of one website which means they share product.  The only gotcha is you have to add products to multiple root categories.  You could have them share the same root, however the product display would be identical. Thank you for the compliment as well.

[image]

This is the setup of the product with the SKU you referenced.

[image]

Comment: 3ky, If this worked! I'm requesting an upvote, as I am competing with my employee on Upvotes this week! :)

Comment: It works like a charm. I've accepted this answer, but I cannot upvote yet, it is enough?

Comment: No that works! Thanks a lot! If you need any other help,  please feel free to ask!

Comment: @Rob Is possible to remove products from categories, remove means    
  un-select from categories.